# Support about Webservice when hosting in IIS

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis

I writing a Web service, when I run it in localhost, everything is OK, but I host in IIS 7.0 , it's not running. Please support me!!!
Here my Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="VivuFace_V2.api.CloudCameraService" behaviorConfiguration="VivuFace_V2.api.CloudCameraServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="../CloudCameraService.svc"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="VivuFace_V2.api.ICloudCameraService"
            behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="VivuFace_V2.api.CloudCameraServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Is there any exception or error message..

Comment: Hi Sasidharan, Please follow the this link to more information, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086610/support-about-web-service-when-hosting-in-iis

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very open ended since there is no error message here, but my experience is that a lot of the time issues related to hosting under IIS is due to the following:

Make sure your app pool is configured for the right version of Net

Make sure asp.net support is installed in IIS

Make sure permissions are configured correctly